# SELECT clause with same data using DISTINCT

Tags: sql, oracle

Example in my employee table i having these data

```
//EMPLOYEE
E#       NAME        CITY
--------------------------
1        JOHN       ENGLAND
2        SITI       ENGLAND
3        JESS       GERMANY
4        HOLY       BOSTON
```

When i run this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY, COUNT(E#) as "Total Employee" FROM EMPLOYEE Where CITY=;
```

what should i insert the value for

```
//CITY=?
```

in order to get the result like this

```
CITY          TOTAL EMPLOYEE
----------------------------
ENGLAND              2
GERMANY              1
BOSTON               1
```

isn't impossible to use group by or having clause?

ANSWER FIXED ! THANKS

Comment: Havn't done any SQL in a while, but I'm pretty sure SELECT DISTINCT is enough to... select distinct values. In your example, you could then just remove you WHERE clause. What did you try so far?

Comment: Thanks you. but i done. just dont know how to delete the thread since got answer

Comment: Well, you don't delete a thread on SO! That would defeat its whole purpose.

Comment: @user3553846 You don't have to necessarily delete the thread. Just upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're not *excluding* any cities, so you don't need a `WHERE` clause at all!  But you DO need a `GROUP BY` to do a count.  You can just do:

```
SELECT CITY, COUNT(E#) as "Total Employee" 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY CITY
```

However if you *only* want to include those three cities (even if more are added to the underlying data), you can do:

```
SELECT CITY, COUNT(E#) as "Total Employee" 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE CITY IN ('ENGLAND', 'GERMANY', 'BOSTON')
GROUP BY CITY
```

Comment: +1 : This should be a `GROUP BY` and not a `DISTINCT` due to its use of the aggregate function `COUNT()`.